# Inserting into list at changing intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I don't know what to call this question**, if a mod can change the title to better reflect the question, please go for it. Feel free to comment name suggestions if you're not a mod. Thanks :)

I'm trying to create a RAID 5 simulation, using Python lists as HDDs. I have successfully simulated RAID 4, where all the parity is on one disk (see [this CodeReview post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163814/raid-4-simulation-for-learning-purposes)). Now I'm trying to distribute the parity across all the disks.

RAID 4: The parity is on one disk, RAID 5: The parity is distibuted

[image: RAID 4 has the parity on one disk]
[image: RAID 5 has the parity distibuted across all disks]

I cannot figure out how to insert the parity into the lists correctly.

Given a list of bytes:
`b = [104, 101, 121, 32, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 32, 66, 111, 98, 98, 121, 33]`

I need it to evenly split between the HDDs (`hdd[0]` - `hdd[3]`), with 0s for padding at the end
`hdd[0] = [104, 32,  101, "p", 98,  33 ]`
`hdd[1] = [101, 116, "p", 32,  98,   0 ]`
`hdd[2] = [121, "p", 114, 66,  121, "p"]`
`hdd[3] = ["p", 104, 101, 111, "p",  0 ]`

I think that the way to do this is to insert the `"p"`s into the list before splitting the list into the HDDs.

I don't know how to do this because the after it inserts one, the list changes, and after inserting the 4th `"p"` it resets back to the first position.

I have tried inserting the `"p"`s as I go, using this (not working) code:
In this example, `hdd_num = 4` (it's the number of HDDs).

```
for i, x in enumerate(input_bytes):
    row = i // (hdd_num - 1)
    hdd = hdds[i % hdd_num]
    if hdd[0] == row:
        input_bytes.insert(i+1, "p")
    hdds[i % hdd_num].append(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be by splitting your code into manageable parts that can be individually tested and reasoned about. Here is a suggestion.

```
def grabChunkOfBytes(byteArray, noChunks):
    chunks = []
    for byte in byteArray:
        chunks.append(byte)
        if len(chunks) == noChunks:
            yield chunks
            chunks = []

    # If the total number of bytes is not divisible by number of disks, 0-fill
    while len(chunks) < noChunks:
        chunks.append(0)
    yield chunks

def computeChecksum(chunks):
    return 'p'  # Your function

def writeChunkToHDDs(chunks, HDDs):
    [hdd.append(part) for hdd, part in zip(HDDs, chunks)]


b = [104, 101, 121, 32, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 32, 66, 111, 98, 98, 121, 33, ]
hdds = [[], [], [], []]
totalHDDs = len(hdds)

for i, chunk in enumerate(grabChunkOfBytes(b, totalHDDs - 1)):
    checksum = computeChecksum(chunk)
    chunk.insert(i % totalHDDs, checksum)
    writeChunkToHDDs(chunk, hdds)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(hdds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sending me down the right path @Andrei. I ended up with the following code:

```
# make blank hdds (with their parity index)
hdds = [[i] for i in range(hdd_num)]

i = 0
# while there are still bytes to store
while len(input_bytes):
    # pop the row from the list
    row = input_bytes[:hdd_num - 1]
    del input_bytes[:hdd_num - 1]

    # add 0s if there aren't enough elements
    while len(row) < hdd_num - 1:
        row.append(0)

    # add the XOR result in the right place
    row.insert(i % hdd_num, xor(row))

    # insert the values into the HDDs
    for j, x in enumerate(row):
        hdds[j].append(x)

    i += 1
```

It uses your ideas of getting the values in each row, inserting the XOR result into the right spot in the row, then adding them to the HDDs. Thanks.

The `xor` function is here:

```
def xor(self, *to_xor):
    """Performs XOR on parameters, from left to right."""
    # if passed a list as it's only argument, xor everything in it
    if len(to_xor) == 1 and \
            isinstance(to_xor[0], (list, tuple, types.GeneratorType)):
        to_xor = to_xor[0]

    x = 0
    for i in to_xor:
        x ^= i
    return x
```